# How CKEditor can access get_absolute_url of the instance

Tags: django, request, ckeditor

everyone!
I'm using CKEditor in my Django project. To upload images, it generates URLs with get_filename function, based on the request:

```
#utils/utils.py
from urllib.parse import urlparse # Будем парсить адрес

def get_filename(filename, request):
    path = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')
    parsed_path = urlparse(path)
    filename = "/".join([parsed_path,filename])
    return filename
```

As far as I update my pages through the user interface, everything go smoth. For example, my news has an address /news/2023/04/test, so CKEditor creates a folder /static/images/news/2023/04/test, and puts images there, which is what I want.
However, if I edit the same news through the admin panel, the path looks different: /admin/news/new/4/, so CKEditor creates a corresponding folder and puts images there, which is wrong.
In other words, the user interface and the admin panel use different paths (and requests) to access the same pages.
I'd like to use get_absolute_url of my models, so CKEditor will use it instead of request string, something like this:

```
def get_filename(filename, get_absolute_url):
    pass
```

How can I pass to CKEditor this parameter?